# Chrome executeScript function not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have an extension I'm writing and I'm trying to execute a script when the user clicks on the pageAction icon. When the icon is clicked, the method calls chrome.tabs.executeScript(...). The problem is that the chrome.tabs.executeScript function is not executing and I can't tell why. I know that I'm getting to the code where it calls executeScript because I have an alert there that appears. Here is some of my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "name here",
  "description": "description here",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16" : "images/icon16.png",
    "48" : "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png" 
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/check.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon19.png",
      "38": "images/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "default title here"
  }
}
```

**js/check.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);

function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tab.url.indexOf('g') > -1) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
};

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert("hello world"); //this code is executed...

  //...this code is not 
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "save.js"}, function() {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
  });
});
```

**js/save.js**

```
alert("hello world");
```

Like I say in the code, the hello world in my pageAction onClick function works. The executeScript method does not. Any idea about what is going on would be helpful.

Comment: Also, the `console.error(...)` code that should fire after the `executeScript(...)` method returns is never called, so that hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing around with lots of different things in my code, I've found the solution to my problem. The error seems to be in the line that says `{file: "save.js"}`. When it's looking for `save.js`, it's apparently looking in the top directory, where my `manifest.json` file is located, not in the directory that my code is in. I had to change my code to `{file: "js/save.js"}` in order for my `save.js` file to be found.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi):

> To insert code into a page, your extension must have [**cross-origin permissions**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html#requesting-permission) for the page. It also must be able to use the `chrome.tabs` module. You can get both kinds of permission using the manifest file's **permissions** field.

So you need a permission for the site, i.e. `http://example.com/` in the permission field.

Comment: I added the `<all_urls>` permission to the manifest just until I get my problem solved, but I'm still getting nothing. No code response or error being shown.

Comment: @mottese does the file exist? Does it contain errors? Any error in the developer console?

Comment: the file exists, all it contains is `alert("hello world");` which contains no errors, and the developer console shows nothing, even though I have explicitly written code saying to print an error.

Comment: @mottese How about the developer console of the page containing `check.js`? (Usually it's the background page)

Comment: I've found the error. Apparently when I write `file: "save.js"`, it is looking in top directory that contains my manifest file. I had to change it to `file: "js/save.js"` in order for it to find the file.

Comment: @mottese if you solved your problem consider adding your answer.